# Mysqli query fast enough? Or is there another way?

Tags: php, mysqli

i am working on a script again and i have some worries about my mysqli queries. The script i am working on is similar to websites like 9gag but with a different background. 
I am listing a bunch of entries in my database and present them to the users. After the user is logged in, he or she can like or dislike each post. I would like to store the like or dislike in a database to prevent the user from liking or disliking the post again. Now i was wondering, if a simple:

```
$db->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ?");
```

would be fast enough if the database continues to get bigger. Do you guys think that it might be better to store the information in a texfile then in a database?
I would love to hear your thoughts about all this. Maybe there is a better and more important faster way to solve this problem.
Thank you very much in advance and excuse my bad english :-)

Comment: If your table is properly indexed on the id column, then it can get much, much bigger without any performance problems.... I suggest you read up about database indexes.... this is what databases are good at doing, and it's why people use databases instead of textfiles

Comment: Do not store such things in textfiles, sql databases are optimized/were created to handle lots of concurrent requests / such tasks, where in comparison read/write ops on your disk perform horribly. Dont worry too much about query performance as of now, you can optimize them when the need arises.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I will read a bit more about the indexes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table has really many rows you can add LIMIT 1 (or 2, or 3, etc.)

```
$db->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ? LIMIT 2");
```

In this case when 2 rows are found the search ends.

If a field is after WHERE it should be indexed. Just click *index* in phpMyAdmin for this field.